# serialize list of dates with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, date-format

I'm trying to serialize an Object that contains a List of Dates and i want to serialize to a JSON list of dates (String) in a specific format (yyyy-MM-dd).

```
private List<Date> executionDates;
```

will become like:

```
"executionDates": [
  "2016-07-22",
  "2016-07-23",
  "2016-07-24"
]
```

It is possible to do it with annotations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with annotations? You mean comments? Also, you can't serialise a list, in order to serialise a list, you need to put the data into a hashset, because hashsets are serialisable.

Comment: Something like this `@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)` on getter of `executionDates` variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to use property `contentUsing` instead of `using` in annotation like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(contentUsing = JsonDateSerializer.class)
```

**contentUsing** property is used for collections. From class documentation:

> Serializer class to use for serializing contents (elements of a
>   Collection/array, values of Maps) of annotated property. Can only be
>   used on properties (methods, fields, constructors), and not value
>   classes themselves (as they are typically generic).

Comment: To everyone watching this: please consider to have consistency between private fields name and getter/setter method: for example if you put an annotation on a private field but its public getter method it's named differently, the final result won't use annotation feature

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

For serialising:

```
@Component
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    // ISO 8601
    private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried but i get this exception: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Date` . Is not being applied to each element in List, but to entire collection.

Comment: Do you have this somewhere in your code? `@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)` EDIT: Have you tried setting the date into a variable type Date, instead of putting the data into an array list?

Comment: Yes, i have like this:  `@JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
 public final List<Date> getExecutionDates() {
  return executionDates;
 }`. With a variable type Date instead of List of Date's, works but i want a list of dates, not just one date...

Comment: Ok, how about you try and take everything in the list, and iterate through it and for every piece of data, make that data into a Date variable, and then serialise it?